# data generator of a regular polygon

Tags: python, data-science, data-generation

Don't know how to do it.

Write a function `C = make_means(k, radius)` that outputs a `k x 2` data matrix `C` containing the 2D coordinates of `k` means (of the data to be generated later). The means of the data generator must lie on the vertices of a regular polygon (if `k=3` the polygon is a equilateral triangle, if `k=6` it is a regular hexagon, etc). Write your own code to determine the position of the vertices of a regular polygon given a radius value (`input radius`) of the circle centered in the origin and inscribing the regular polygon. The first point of the polygon on the x-axis.

For example `make_means(3, radius=1)` would yield:

> [[ 1. ,  0.       ],

> [-0.5 ,  0.8660254],

> [-0.5 , -0.8660254]]

here is my code:

```
for i in range(0, 360, 72):
    theta = np.radians(i)
    mean = np.array([1., 0.])
    c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
    cov = np.array(((c, -s), (s, c)))
    C = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, size= 1000)
    #C
    plt.scatter(C[:, 0], C[:, 1])
```

but it seems does not appear to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

```
x_values = []
    y_values = []
    for i in range(k):
        angle = 2 * np.pi / k
        x = radius * np.cos(i * angle)
        y = radius * np.sin(i * angle)
        x_values.append(x)
        y_values.append(y)
    A = np.c_[x_values,y_values]
```

its something as simple as this.